# Is Entity Framework Core suitable for high load web applications?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Please consider these assumptions:

1. I have a high traffic web application with millions records in database tables.
2. Suppose I know enough about `EF` and how to properly use it in its optimal way.
3. I prefer to use `EF` in my applications due to its compatibility with `OOP` and ease of use.

I know `EF` (even with best practice usages) has some performance downsides in compare with `Dapper` or `ADO.NET`.

But my question is that based on my assumptions, is this performance issue considerable or I can use `EF` safely in my high traffic web application?

Comment: What do you mean by "compliance with OOP"?

Comment: @Dai: I mean it's `ORM` so you can use it more objective and don't pollute the code with native sql commands

Comment: Reopening. This is partially opinion based, but this is something a lot of people stumble upon and it is an opinion as far as "is buning a computer a good way to do a backup" - the evidence of good and bad "benavior" with regards to EF (core) is empirical and somethign a lot of people struggle with.

Comment: It is an unanswerable question, because the answer is different for all possible use cases. It is opinion-based because what is "safely", what is "considerable"? Compared to what?Also, there's no objective way to evaluate non-functional requirements like development and maintenance costs using EF vs alternatives.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have a high-traffic web application with millions records in database tables.

No one (mostly not the database) cares about millions of records unless you forget to put indices on it. Way more interesting is how complex the queries are. Most queries - particularly those that can use an index at least to reduce the numbers parsed - are trivial load on billions of records, but a join over 15 tables hat forces 100gb of data into tempdb is a problem.

> I know enough about EF and how to properly use it in its most optimize way.

I doubt that, particularly for EF Core which seems to change every weekend. But ok, you do avoid the most stupid things, like one dbcontext for the whole application.

> I know EF even with best practice usages has some performance downsides in compare with Dapper or ADO.

This is so totally not true. The point is more - EF does a lot that neither Dapper nor ADO directly do, and this comes with a price. This is like "A Ferrari is faster than a truck, but there are downsides".

The truck is slow - except if you transport a lot of stuff. I.e. queries come with a lot of overhead - but if you do not care about ever updating the data you query (typical in web applications), then turn off change tracking for this query. Getting objects has an overhead - ok, happens.

But you can filter which properties you materialize. Do it and the amount of data goes down. EF is not exactly super fast - but it is not exactly awful either. Dapper and ADO(.NET) beat it, but they do less.

In fact, EF is built on top of ADO.NET, because unless you plan to write the whole network stack yourself, ADO.NET is the only way to talk to most databases.

The whole problem is: what do you think is high traffic? I have seen EF successfully deployed in applications with tens of thousands of parallel users. I have then made some critical functions 100 times faster because the pro programmers knew everything about EF - but no one taught them how to put the proper indices on tables.

EF is perfectly capable on large applications, but depending on usage you may have to scale to some servers, unless you write very efficient user level code and avoid inefficient things like enumerating all values and then filtering in memory (and yes, I have seen this - particularly with "we do repositories around EF" people that then thought returning an `IEnumerable` is a good idea).

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in EF that will inhibit your application's *scalability*.  If there is a performance difference, you can compensate with additional resources.  And you can manage the tradeoff between resource cost and development cost on a case-by-case basis, rather than making an up-front Architecture Decision.

And an EF application with selected performance-critical transactions implemented in ADO.NET and/or Stored Procedures is typically not materially slower or more expensive to run than an application written *entirely* with ADO.NET and Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you're aware of best practices, and beware of absolute "DO NOT"s, yes it is. There always will be developers who don't know what they're doing and joins a List<> object into a Linq query which will result fetching all records on that table. There always be another who joins or includes all relations when it is not necessary. And another who fetches the entity with all of its fields when the code actually needs one field from that entity.

We're using entity framework core in a big government project, having hundreds of millions data in many tables and having hundreds of requests per second in a work day. As long as you also optimize table indexes and relationships correctly, it's all fine. It's not about the library, it is about whether you use it wisely or not.

Answer (score -1):

Dapper encourages to write plain SQL and thus you can have more control if you are a SQL expert; you can write complex queries the way you like. It is still faster than EF core. There are certain verbosity with EF core using code-first. For instance for composite foreign key you have to override OnModelCreating and specify the rules. Further to specify different table-names other than the model you have to write code for it. If you happen to make changes in the Migration table(which usually happens during testing) then you might have to do the subsequent commits (for model changes) manually in the database after generating the scripts and analyzing the difference visually.

**The question is "Do we have to think of ways to optimize Dapper?"** Then answer is "No, it is by default optimized".

**Another question is "Do we have to think of ways to optimize EF core?"** Then answer is "Yes, you have to take lot of things into consideration".

Comment: *Tracking the changes is even more difficult.* -- What do you mean? Using what? EF or Dapper? *It takes a lot of pain to set up things with EF core* -- I totally disagree. Try to "set things up" for an entire application using Dapper in a maintainable, type-safe way. It's orders of magnitude more difficult and error-prone.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, I was trying to mean something else. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Frankly, nobody will only use Dapper for the data layer of an entire application. It's far too narrow to only look at optimization for speed (which BTW, EF-core 6 is approaching now). It's not the only design decision, *by far*. At any rate, it's virtually useless to answer vague questions like this.

Comment: There are people who would still use EF and wrap their head around managing and maintaining it. It is needless to say that Dapper has always been faster, simpler and easier to use as a mini ORM. There has been lot of issues with EF benchmarking in the past and it is gradually improving. Needless to say there is a learning curve with EF and its migration pattern. Please love to use layers on top of ADO.NET for ease provided they are ready to pay the price of maintaining the layer.

Comment: Well, it's getting more and more hazy. You lost me.

Comment: Here, let me make it easy for you. Dapper is still faster and is easier to learn than EF.